# Not able to inject dependency in jasmine test, getting Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appConfigProvider <- appConfig

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write up a jasmine test but the the test doesn't inject any dependency declared in the module 'myApp'. For example: for dependency (constant) value appConfig it throws error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appConfigProvider <- appConfig
```

code snippet:

```
describe("UI grid custom directive test", function() {

    var $rootScope, $compile;
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, TestUtils, appConfig) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    console.log(appConfig);
    TestUtils.test();
    $compile = _$compile_;
    var elm = angular.element(
        '<custom-ui-grid></custom-ui-grid>'
    );
    $compile(elm)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
}));
```

Bootstraping the application in app-init.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
     ...
]);

...
app.value('appConfig', {
        appRootPath: appRootPath
    });
..
```

Karma.unit.config.js

```
files: [
....
        //App-specific Code
        './main/webapp/app/app-init.js',
        './main/webapp/app/config.js',
.....
```

Comment: It's not the mock that thorws the exception. Did you specify the location of appConfig file in your testing base file?

Comment: @DennisNerush I have edited the question to give some more details. I have verified that the file in which constant is being declared is in karma.unit.config.js and does referred by the webpage on chrome.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with this TestUtils. To have the appConfig value available, you just need to make sure that app-init.js is loaded by karma, and that you have `beforeEach(module('myApp'))` in the test (assuming myApp is the module in which appConfig is defined).

Comment: @JB Nizet : Removed TestUtill to simplify (it was included as was the first place to encounter error)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!!

In one of the deceleration of the directive, module was being created instead of being reused/imported.

```
function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);//notice the '[]'
    ...
```

Because I was creating the module again, all the declaration, configurations in app-init.js was being wiped out. Corrected it to

```
function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
    ...
```

and it worked out well.